# Setting a string containing a variable to be checked when string is used - Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, variables, hash, ruby-1.9.3

Apologies in advance for what I think might be a stupid question. I promise I have searched, but I'm not sure if I've searched for the correct things. I'm a very new programmer, Ruby is my first serious language, and I taught myself it over the past few months. I've also never asked a question on StackOverflow, so hopefully this is acceptably clear and meets the other requirements for question-asking. Here is the question:

I have a branching method that calls various different APIs and various different URLs within them, based upon the values passed to the method. As is, it looks like:

```
if api == x
url = "http://url.x.com/api/#{@variable}"
elsif api == y
url = "http://url.y.com/api/public/#{@var1}_#{@var2}/#{@variable}"
```

etc.

The url's being called are different for each operation, as are the necessary variables. The variables used in the requests are being created as instance variables at the beginning of the method. The possible values of the instance variables are stored in a large hash or are being passed into the method by the call itself. The hash is structured like:

```
$globalhash = 
{
"api_1" => 
{
"call_type_1" => {"info_1" => "", "info_2" => ""},
"call_type_2" => {"info_1" => "", "info_2" => ""}
},
"api_2" =>
{
"call_type_1" => {"info_1" => "", "info_2" => ""},
"call_type_2" => {"info_1" => "", "info_2" => ""}
}
}
```

The problem I have is that this branching section goes on for a long time in the code--partially because I've done it suboptimally, I'm sure. I'm also sure that my code would be much more efficient if the branching section didn't exist. Ideally, instead of the branching section, I'd like to make this happen:

```
url = $globalhash[@api][@call_type]["url"]
```

The value that pulls would be a URL specific to the call type and the api--the address, formatting, and various other differences included. So some values would be:

```
http://api.x.com/@var1_@var2/@variable
http://api.y.com/public/@variable
```

and so on. So the structures vary, and I need to access the instance variables stored within the method call, but I need to do so dynamically. The issue I've had is that every way I've tried to implement this results in the values of the instance variables in the strings for "url" being set when $globalhash is read as the program begins to run, with them all being nil. I need it to check the variable when the request is being made, and not before, basically. I have a similar (same?) issue with setting the post_data for the request--if I could find a way to set it in the hash, I'd have cleaner code that runs faster. The post_data is as:

```
post_data = {'value' => @var1, 'value2' => @var2, 'value3' => @var3}
```

and so on. The post_data is different for each API and for each call_type; the values are different as are the requested variables for them. I'd like to implement a set of key-value pairs in the hash that look vaguely like:

```
$globalhash = {"api_1" => {"call_type_1" => {"url" => "http://api.x.com/#{@variable}", "post_data" => "{'value' => @var1, 'value2' => @var2, etc.}"}}}
```

Except, of course, it would need to work--the variables it needs to reference are nil when $globalhash is being read. I'm not sure how best to solve this.

The program works as-is, but I have a very derpy-looking ~80 lines of branching code that figures out the structure of the URL and the post_data, and then requests it.

The only solution I've considered is creating an instance hash within the method to replace the branching code, that only gets created after declaring the instance variables. However, I'm afraid that would create a similar problem to the current one, of it being inefficient to create a huge new hash every time.

Thanks for reading, and I appreciate your help. I hope the pseudo-code is acceptable, I found it the best way to explain my question.

EDIT: Found a solution. Code:

```
url = eval "\"#{$globalhash["api_1"]["call_type_1"]["url"]}\""
```

["url"] references 'http://api.x.com/#{@variable}', single quotes prevent interpolation within the hash, eval function puts it in double quotes and string interpolation collects the instance variable at the time it is called. It's an ugly methodology BUT it does let me greatly shorten my code. Source: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3237101

Comment: It's quite difficult understand your question although it may be a trivial problem. I'd suggest to rephrase it or summarize what you have and what you need/expect. Btw. you can check existence of a key with `Hash#has_key?`, for nested hashes either write a helper method or rely on `Hash#fetch` and handle `KeyError` exception.

Comment: tl;dr: I currently have an 80-line branching if statement to figure out the requested url and the post_data. I want to replace it with:

url = $globalhash[@api][@call_type]["url"]
post_data = $globalhash[@api][@call_type]["post_data"]

or something similar, but I can't figure out how to do so. I basically want a way to store a string containing a variable as a value in a hash, but I only want it to check the value of the variable when I reference it, not when the hash is originally read. Is that possible, or is something similar possible?

Comment: You've just written it. Create a nested hash object like described and retrieve a value with `myhash.fetch(@api).fetch(@call_type).fetch('url')` and `rescue KeyError`. Btw. avoid global variables unless you exactly know what you are doing.

Comment: No, that does not work--the problem is still the same: the url itself needs to contain instance variables placed in differing areas in order to be correct. The solution I have found is to create:

$globalhash[@api][@call_type][@call_subtype]['url']

and hard code in the values I want to be variables. The problem is this results in adding 500+ values to the hash, as there are a LOT of potential subtypes and so on. So I'm still not satisfied as I feel there must be a better answer.

Thanks for the warning on global variables. It's fine for this program but I am cautious about them.

Comment: I can probably reduce the number of subtypes by grouping them etc., but still not really a satisfactory answer. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: It's still not clear character of data you are trying to handle. Do they frequently share common values ? Then hash is not the most appropriate structure and would look for an ordered tree like Trie.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the hash using the instance variables...

```
post_data = {'value' => @var1, 'value2' => @var2, 'value3' => @var3}
```

...you could initialize the hash using strings representing the instance variables.

```
post_data = {'value' => '@var1', 'value2' => '@var2', 'value3' => '@var3'}
```

Then when you reference the hash variable, you would wrap the call in an eval.

```
post_data = {'value' => '@var1', 'value2' => '@var2', 'value3' => '@var3'}

@var2 = 'this is test data'

eval(post_data['value2'])
=> "this is test data"
```

Similarly I would use placeholders in the url...

```
url =  'http://api.x.com/[@variable]'

@variable = "cotton_tree"

my_url = url.dup

my_url.sub!(/\[.*?\]/, eval(my_url.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1])) while my_url.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)

p my_url
=> "http://api.x.com/cotton_tree"
```